# Removing duplicates at the end of macro selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to select a range of names based on date. I then want to remove the duplicates in the selection. My macro runs fine however it does not remove duplicates like it is supposed to and returns no errors. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
sub Remove_Duplicates()

    Dim mRow As Long
    Dim mStart As Long, mEnd As Long
    Dim rng As Range


    Worksheets("Weekely").Select
    For mRow = 1 To 65536
        If Range("G" & mRow).Value = "2016" Then
            mStart = mRow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next mRow

    ' Figure out where the "2016" data ends.
    For mRow = mStart To 65536
        If Range("G" & mRow).Value <> "2016" Then
            mEnd = mRow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next mRow
    mEnd = mEnd - 1

    Set rng = Range("G" & mStart & ":G" & mEnd).Offset(0, 1)

    rng.RemoveDuplicates

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rng.RemoveDuplicates` won't throw an error but also does nothing.  You need to specifyy the Column(s) for which the duplicate needs to removed . Also specify whether you have header or not.

Assuming you don't have a header cell and just one column `H`

Correct way :
`rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo`

Comment: Also, if it solves your query then mark it as answer.

Comment: I checked it, Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: yes. that's about it. Always accept answers which solves your problem . Good practice :)